# Error with DataStax Commuity on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I got this Error if i want to Setup the Datastax Cassandra Cluster (Community Edition), i have used this:

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/install/install_ami

```
[EXEC] 06/05/13-10:52:05 sudo rm -rf /etc/motd
[EXEC] 06/05/13-10:52:05 sudo touch /etc/motd
[INFO] Started with user data set to:
[INFO] --clustername myDSCcluster --totalnodes 3 --version community
[INFO] Using instance type: m1.large
[ERROR] Exception seen in ds1_launcher.py:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/ubuntu/datastax_ami/ds1_launcher.py", line 31, in initial_configurations      
  ds2_configure.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/datastax_ami/ds2_configure.py", line 932, in run      
  File "/home/ubuntu/datastax_ami/ds2_configure.py", line 125, in get_ec2_data      
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)     
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)      
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)     
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Hello danny and welcome to stackoverflow. Any time you post code it would be useful if you use the code tag `{ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you may have attempted to launch the cluster within a VPC, which isn't supported.

I did, however, notice that we don't specifically mention that VPC's aren't supported. I'll make sure we get that fixed.

Comment: Hi joaquin, VPC is it still not supported? I'm facing the same issue, and don't know how to launch an EC2 instance not on a VPC. Thanks